# How to expand mat-expansion-panel based on-click button in angular?

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, mat-expansion-panel

I have a component with expansion panels, and now, On-clicking of All tab button, in the  below body part all the mat-expansion-panel is expanding perfectly, and what i am expecting is: if we click on the B tab it should be active and B alphabet  mat-expansion-panel only needs to expand, and on-click of C tab it should be active and c alphabet  mat-expansion-panel only needs to expand. Based on the "alphabet and on-click tab" it should expand.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-jyfo5x?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)

Comment: Provide your code for a better understanding.

Comment: Hi kirubel please check the stackBlitz for reference.

Comment: I have updated your provided sample code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-52fro8?file=app/expansion-overview-example.ts). please check this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. You can check this [mat-expansion example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-hvzfno?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html) link

Comment: Hey @ManiselvamR , I didn't get your point but I have updated my code. Please check if it is fulfilling your requirement or not.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-za1twz?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts

Comment: Hey @ManiselvamR, Again , I have updated the code. Please check this out
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-ct2xhq?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts

Comment: Hi anil veram, i have missed to inform one more thing like if we click B tab it gets expand and if we click A tab it's gets expand but B expansion also needs to be open and active it's closed when we click other tab, example if we click A and B the both should open and active.please check and update stack-blitz thanks